# How can I combine two shaders into one?

Tags: merge, glsl, shader

I wanted to merge two shaders into one, but it just doesn't loads when I try. I used openai to merge them but seems like the code is broken and I don't know the GLSL language. It would be awesome if it can be helped.

Where I'm trying to use it on: Minecraft resource packs.

Shader 1 does spacing to minimize lag and Shader 2 is for moving level number of minecraft and recoloring it.

Shader 1:

```
#version 110

#moj_import <fog.glsl>
#moj_import <light.glsl>

in vec3 Position;
in vec4 Color;
in vec2 UV0;
in ivec2 UV2;

uniform sampler2D Sampler0;

uniform mat4 ModelViewMat;
uniform mat4 ProjMat;
uniform mat3 IViewRotMat;
uniform int FogShape;
uniform vec2 ScreenSize;

out float vertexDistance;
out vec4 vertexColor;
out vec2 texCoord0;

#define ACTIONBAR_OFFSET 64

// Function to convert a vertical ascent into a ID.
float get_id(float offset) {
    if (offset <= 0)
        return 0;
    return trunc(offset/1000);
}


void main() {
    vec3 pos = Position;

    vertexDistance = fog_distance(ModelViewMat, IViewRotMat * Position, FogShape);
    vertexColor = Color;
    texCoord0 = UV0;

    vec2 pixel = vec2(ProjMat[0][0], ProjMat[1][1]) / 2.0;
    int guiScale = int(round(pixel.x / (1 / ScreenSize.x)));
    vec2 guiSize = ScreenSize / guiScale;

    float id = get_id((round(guiSize.y - Position.y + ACTIONBAR_OFFSET)) * -1);
    
    // Detect if GUI text.
    if (id > 99 && Color.a != 0.0) {
        float yOffset = 0;
        float xOffset = 0;
        int layer = 0;
        bool outlined = false;

        switch (int(id)) {
%POSITIONS%
        }

        if (%OUTLINE_CONDITION%) {
            pos.y -= (id*1000) + 500 - ACTIONBAR_OFFSET;
            pos.x -= (guiSize.x * 0.5);
            pos -= vec3(xOffset, yOffset, 0.0);
            pos.z += layer;
        }
    }   

    gl_Position = ProjMat * ModelViewMat * vec4(pos, 1);
}
```

Shader 2:

```
#version 150

#moj_import <fog.glsl>

in vec3 Position;
in vec4 Color;
in vec2 UV0;
in ivec2 UV2;

uniform sampler2D Sampler2;

uniform mat4 ModelViewMat;
uniform mat4 ProjMat;
uniform mat3 IViewRotMat;
uniform int FogShape;
uniform vec2 ScreenSize;

out float vertexDistance;
out vec4 vertexColor;
out vec2 texCoord0;

bool isAt(int offset, int vID, int pos) {
    return (((vID == 1 || vID == 2) && offset == pos) || ((vID == 0 || vID == 3) && offset == (pos+8)));
}

void main() {
    vec3 pos = Position;

    vertexDistance = fog_distance(ModelViewMat, IViewRotMat * Position, FogShape);
    vertexColor = Color;
    texCoord0 = UV0;
    
    // get the size of a text pixel
    vec2 pixel = vec2(ProjMat[0][0], ProjMat[1][1]) / 2.0;
    // get the gui scale
    int guiScale = int(round(pixel.x / (1 / ScreenSize.x)));
    // get the size of the gui space
    vec2 guiSize = ScreenSize / guiScale;
    // get the vertex id for each specific character
    int vID = gl_VertexID % 4;
    // get the offset from the bottom 
    int offset = int(round(guiSize.y - Position.y));
    
    // offset xp text
    if(Position.z == 0.0 // z location is always 0 
        && ((length(Color.rgb - vec3(0.501, 1.0, 0.125)) < 0.002 && (isAt(offset, vID, 26) || isAt(offset, vID, 27))) // the bright text starts 27 pixels from the bottom, sometimes at 26
        || (length(Color.rgb - vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)) < 0.002 && (isAt(offset, vID, 25) || isAt(offset, vID, 26) || isAt(offset, vID, 27) || isAt(offset, vID, 28))))) { // the darker background consists out of 3 elements (26,27,28), sometimes (25,26,27)
        
        /** Reposition (Remove up to Reposition End if unnecessary)**/
        pos += vec3(0.0,10.0,0.0); // apply an offset
        /* Reposition End */
        
        /** Recolor (Remove up to Recolor End if unnecessary)**/
        if(length(Color.rgb - vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)) < 0.002) {
            vertexColor = vec4(0.4431, 0.3294, 0, 1); // shadow (usually black)
        } else {
            vertexColor = vec4(0.8784, 0.6627, 0, 1); // text (usually green)
        }
        /* Recolor End */
          
    }
    
    gl_Position = ProjMat * ModelViewMat * vec4(pos, 1.0);
}
```

The code I tried:

```
#version 150

#moj_import <fog.glsl>
#moj_import <light.glsl>

in vec3 Position;
in vec4 Color;
in vec2 UV0;
in ivec2 UV2;

uniform sampler2D Sampler2;
uniform sampler2D Sampler0;

uniform mat4 ModelViewMat;
uniform mat4 ProjMat;
uniform mat3 IViewRotMat;
uniform int FogShape;
uniform vec2 ScreenSize;

out float vertexDistance;
out vec4 vertexColor;
out vec2 texCoord0;

#define ACTIONBAR_OFFSET 64

// Function to convert a vertical ascent into a ID.
float get_id(float offset) {
    if (offset <= 0)
        return 0;
    return trunc(offset/1000);
}

bool isAt(int offset, int vID, int pos) {
    return (((vID == 1 || vID == 2) && offset == pos) || ((vID == 0 || vID == 3) && offset == (pos+8)));
}

void main() {
    vec3 pos = Position;

    vertexDistance = fog_distance(ModelViewMat, IViewRotMat * Position, FogShape);
    vertexColor = Color;
    texCoord0 = UV0;

    vec2 pixel = vec2(ProjMat[0][0], ProjMat[1][1]) / 2.0;
    int guiScale = int(round(pixel.x / (1 / ScreenSize.x)));
    vec2 guiSize = ScreenSize / guiScale;

    float id = get_id((round(guiSize.y - Position.y + ACTIONBAR_OFFSET)) * -1);

    // Detect if GUI text.
    if (id > 99 && Color.a != 0.0) {
        float yOffset = 0;
        float xOffset = 0;
        int layer = 0;
        bool outlined = false;

        switch (int(id)) {
            %POSITIONS%
        }

        if (%OUTLINE_CONDITION%) {
            pos.y -= (id*1000) + 500 - ACTIONBAR_OFFSET;
            pos.x -= (guiSize.x * 0.5);
            pos -= vec3(xOffset, yOffset, 0.0);
            pos.z += layer;

            if(Position.z == 0.0 // z location is always 0 
                && ((length(vertexColor.rgb - vec3(0.501, 1.0, 0.125)) < 0.002 && (isAt(int(round(guiSize.y - Position.y)), gl_VertexID % 4, 26) || isAt(int(round(guiSize.y - Position.y)), gl_VertexID % 4, 27))) // the bright text starts 27 pixels from the bottom, sometimes at 26
                || (length(vertexColor.rgb - vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)) < 0.002 && (isAt(int(round(guiSize.y - Position.y)), gl_VertexID % 4, 25) || isAt(int(round(guiSize.y - Position.y)), gl_VertexID % 4, 26) || isAt(int(round(guiSize.y - Position.y)), gl_VertexID % 4, 27) || isAt(int(round(guiSize.y - Position.y)), gl_VertexID % 4, 28))))) { // the darker background consists out of 3 elements (26,27,28), sometimes (25
```

Comment: This person who downvoted seems to ask for close as need more focus. And I agree that your question seems broad. What did you tried, where are you stuck exactly? What's wrong with your code? I suggest you to [edit] your post and add content (also, I think the [tag:minecraft] tag isn't necessary)

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, it's my first time here and I might not know how to make a proper question here. I will edit the post with the code I tried.

Comment: Oh yes, Welcome ! You can read [ask] and/or take the [tour] to have all informations about how to ask :)